# Can I put information from an API to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The title is the best I can really phrase it, however, heres my Microsoft Paint version of what I'm trying to do. If you guys know how to do it feel free to reply.

Heres what it is doing

[image: What it is doing right now]

Heres what I want it to do

[image: What I want it to do]

Sorry for the bad drawings not the most artistic.

Comment: Does the API get called from the `index.html` and the process data will load to `2ndPage.html`?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion No, the API gets called from my app.js file, I have the form.js as a <div class="root"></div> in my index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whats the use case you are trying to solve, but I will assume that it is something similar to how search could work. ie: You enter something in input fields, push submit button -> hide form you are currently in and show results in next page.

Pseudo code could look like this

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    results: null
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({query: e.target.value})
  }

  formSubmit = () => {
    //do your request to api
       .then(response => this.setState({results: response}))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      this.state.results === null ? (
        <form>
           <input type="text" value={this.state.query} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
           <button type="submit" onClick={this.formSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      ):(
        <div>{this.state.results}</div>
      )
    ) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was the most informative, however, I still dont quite understand how I'd implement this. Also sorry for the lack of information I gave, I'm making a weather app as a little project, this is how I have it setup, I have an app.js that calls the API, then the form.js which is just simple JSX of a form setup, and then weather.js which is also JSX that just has the format in which the information gets placed. In the end, I have an index.html which has a div class as root to have the forms in the html. If you have a Discord I can send you a few screenshots.

Comment: @looskie If you would add you code to codeSandbox, I could probably help you out.

Answer (score 1):

React basically is a single page application so one way in doing what you want is to use [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) when the submit button is clicked, you send the form data to the backend and then dispatch a new route that will display the component that has the `API` data. inside the `componentDidMount` life cycle of the component that will display the api data you make a fetch to get the data.